# Variable arity functions in Racket/C FFI

Tags: c, racket, ffi

Declaring functions with Racket's FFI is simple enough to do with [`_fun`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/foreign_procedures.html?q=_fun#%28form._%28%28lib._ffi%2Funsafe..rkt%29.__fun%29%29) and [`define-ffi-definer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/Defining_Bindings.html?q=define-ffi-definer#%28form._%28%28lib._ffi%2Funsafe%2Fdefine..rkt%29._define-ffi-definer%29%29). (A tutorial can be found on [the PRL blog](http://prl.ccs.neu.edu/blog/2016/06/27/tutorial-using-racket-s-ffi/)) For example, I can make a binding for [`atoi`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi):

```
#lang racket
(require ffi/unsafe
         ffi/unsafe/define)
(define-ffi-definer define-libc #f)
(define-libc atoi (_fun _string -> _int))
```

And now I can call `atoi` with Racket strings:

```
> (atoi "5")
5
```

The problem now is, how do I call C functions with a variable arity, such as [`printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), who's signature is:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

I would guess that (since the linking happens dynamically), the Racket code should have a 'rest' argument at the end, which takes an array (pointer) for the rest of the arguments, that is either null terminated or (more likely), indicated by yet another argument. However, I can't think of any good ways to test this.

So, how do you handle variable arity functions with the Racket-C FFI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this solution [c-printf](https://github.com/mflatt/min-racket/blob/master/collects/ffi/examples/c-printf.rkt):

```
(provide c-printf)

(define interfaces (make-hash))

(define (c-printf fmt . args)
  (define itypes
    (cons _string
          (map (lambda (x)
                 (cond [(and (integer? x) (exact? x)) _int]
                       [(and (number? x) (real? x))   _double*]
                       [(string? x)  _string]
                       [(bytes? x)   _bytes]
                       [(symbol? x)  _symbol]
                       [else (error 'c-printf
                                    "don't know how to deal with ~e" x)]))
               args)))
  (let ([printf (hash-ref interfaces itypes
                  (lambda ()
                    ;; Note: throws away the return value of printf
                    (let ([i (get-ffi-obj "printf" #f
                                          (_cprocedure itypes _void))])
                      (hash-set! interfaces itypes i)
                      i)))])
    (apply printf fmt args)))
```